# Myeclipse WebBrowser Error - document cannot be displayed while offline

Tags: eclipse, offline, myeclipse

I have MyEclipse Version: 2015 Stable 2.0. When i try to open WebBrowser on any site.. the following appears:

> This document cannot be displayed while offline. To go online, uncheck Work Offline from the File menu.

I tried with

> -vmargs
>   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

and shows nothing..

> java version "1.7.0_79"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
>   OpenJDK Client VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

I had to change settings
[image settings](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9uoxioa72o0male/2015-10-06%2023_17_49-Inicio.png?dl=0)

any ideas
appreciate your vote for reputation

Comment: To be clear: were you offline? Does the MyEclipse dashboard show latest news and can you go to the learning center pages from the Help menu?

Comment: MyEclipse learning no problem

[img1](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/5vCeQFqKNP2sccudausuO0xjTJ2mrv-dHrpeQCYHQtA)

 but Delivery Log not show correctly [img2](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/fYWdc8CvvRfvoVtiIgwPI0xjTJ2mrv-dHrpeQCYHQtA)

when i start a web site on internal web browser show me that [img3](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/8ZH3UYezMBq-GswbAEXXyExjTJ2mrv-dHrpeQCYHQtA)

on ubuntu 14.04 32bits

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with certain Linux systems, where an internal browser view isn't available. [See here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux) for the requirements to run an internal browser.

If the requirements can't be met then you'd need to test on an external browser. The MyEclipse delivery log seems to be a related problem but can be viewed [here](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/deliverylog/stable/) (for the stable stream) or [here](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/deliverylog/ci/) (for the CI - continuous integration - stream).